# ID naming convention in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, naming-conventions

Coming from the world of HTML, XML and PHP its a new way of thinking when making web applications using ASP.NET. I'd like to use the following code in my MasterPage:

```
<div id="leftnav">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="leftnav" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

But since `leftnav` in this example is used twice, Visual Studio make a small but noticable protest. How should I think in this situation, and which is the most appropriate use of naming ID's in ASP.NET.

I don't like the default naming since `id="ContentPlaceHolder1"` says nothing of the content.

Thank you for listening!

Comment: Do you really need to give the div an ID?
Btw, i prefer to give controls an ID which gives a conclusion to its type, f.e. DivLeftNav, CphLeftNav or TxtLeftNav.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: given the question, couldn't we just assume that there's a reason why OP needs it...? after all, it's not uncommon to need IDs.

Comment: The general idea is to make a simple style of the page, thus using leftnav as a reference for my stylesheet where #leftnav { float: left; width: 190px; } and #content { margin-left: 200px; }.

It might be I'm thinking all wrong here, since I'm new to ASP :)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: giving an ID that includes the type will look funny if the DIV becomes a SPAN later...

Comment: @ck: to what extent are we supposed to future-proof our code, though? i totally buy it in the case of daniel dyson's answer, because there it's a question about different concerns entirely, but can we say that the same is the case here? an ID that *only* describes what the element does, will be misleading if we change what it does. surely, to some extent we have to be willing to follow up code changes we do, with further code changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would call the div "nav" and the placeholder "navPlaceholder". This is because the word "left" implies **position, which should be handled soley by your css**, not your html. What if the designers decided they wanted to put the navigation on the right? You could do this in your css, but you would end up with something confusing like `div #lefnav { float:right; }` a trivial example, I know but something to keep in mind.

Comment: a sensible approach. +1 for separating our concerns

Comment: Thanx Daniel. I've changed the names to globalNav, localNav and supplementNav to better describe its content, rather than style or position. Sincerely,

Answer (score 3):

How about "leftNavPlaceHolder"?

Just as along as your consistent with your naming convention :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the default IDs are terrible. I can't imagine they're meant to be used, it's just that Visual Studio isn't intelligent enough to suggest anything better, and they're not suggesting something semi-intelligent, because they don't want to try to come off as something they're not. Reasonable =)

So make a habit of *always* changing the default IDs. What you change them to is completely up to you; "leftNavContent"? Pretty much the only thing that's coverned by convention is capitalization, when it comes to IDs.

The only thing that should *really* change from pure HTML is that you can't use IDs like "left-navigation", i.e. containing hyphens, for server controls.

Comment: +1 for "make a habit of always changing the default IDs" They are meaningless and make any client side scripting harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, don't give id to div unless you really need, because it will impact on performance.

Comment: the 11 extra characters being sent to the client? notice that the DIV is not `runat="server"`. OP is talking about a *smallbut noticable protest* in the designer - not a compile error =)

Comment: I am talking to whole html controls id not for single ID

Comment: I think if you have much html on page, and you unnessceraly id, it will have impact on performance, although it is minor.

Answer (score 1):

Subjective. The obvious answer to this type of question is: Pick something that you like; standardise it, and always follow it.

Personally, I name my things in the following fashion:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlDescriptionOfContent" />
```

or

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plhSendMessage">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

For an area that contains, yes, information about sending a message. But you don't have to do this. Do whatever you want. Just make it consistent. And ideally, convey a little information about what is within.

Comment: That's a nice way of thinking, just like ordinary C# naming conventions. I just thought there were a simple naming convention around, that everybody uses. Thanx for your answer.

Comment: This is very sensible advice too.

Answer (score 1):

I prefix all ASP.Net controls with `ux` to mean user control.

Then you can hook up your `String emailAddress = "test@abc.com";` to your `uxEmailAddress.Text = emailAddress`